# Why do people write: " /// <method> /// Some method description /// </method>", where did this style of commenting came from?

Tags: methods, comments

```
 /// <method>
 /// Open Database Connection if Closed or Broken
 /// </method>
 public void MyMethod () {...}
```

I've just started learning C# and I've seen this style of commenting a number of times. Could anyone tell me if there is a reason behind why people comment this way, and where did this style of commenting came from?

Comment: [These are used for generating documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b2s063f7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [XML Documentation Comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx), and can be used by tools such as the C# compiler /doc option and Sandcastle to automatically generate API documentation.